# How to make a timer in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a question on my code.
Now ,I  make a Text UI to show on the screen after a collision, and I also want to make  the text disappear after 2 seconds so that after another new collision, it can appear again. So, how can I make a timer to get this function? 
Thanks a lot!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CollisionWithPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    int score;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        score = 0;
        GameObject.Find("message").GetComponent<Text>().text ="";
        GameObject.Find("collect").GetComponent<Text>().text = "";
        GameObject.Find("score").GetComponent<Text>().text = "";

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        print("Collided with " + collision.collider.gameObject.tag);
        if (collision.collider.gameObject.tag == "pick_me")
        {
            GameObject.Find("collect").GetComponent<Text>().text = "You have collected an object!";
            Destroy(collision.collider.gameObject);
            //yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
            //Destroy(GameObject.Find("collect"));
            score++;
            GameObject.Find("score").GetComponent<Text>().text = "score = " + score;
            print("Score " + score);

        }
        if (collision.collider.gameObject.name == "end" && score == 4)
        {
            print("Congratulations!");
            GameObject.Find("message").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Congratulations!";
        }
    }
}
```

In my code, I have 4 balls belong to "pick_me".And I want the text  "You have collected an object!" appear at the time the player collide with the ball, then disappear after 2 seconds, the next time, the player collide with another ball, the text appears again.
So what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) with [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html). For example:

```cs
IEnumerable OnCollisionCoroutine()
{
    // Do stuff here to make the text visible

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    // Do stuff here to hide the text
}
```

Then, when a collision is detected, call:

```cs
StartCoroutine(OnCollisionCoroutine());
```

Comment: I update my code, can you help me again! I try your code, but it does not work well! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have added a hint to my answer, but you really need to read the documentation to understand how coroutines work. In addition to the two links I already gave [here's another page](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/coroutines) that might be helpful:  You'll also find a ton of info on coroutines by searching the internet for phrases like "unity coroutine tutorial."

Comment: OK! Thanks a lot! You are very helpful!

Comment: Happy to help. If my answer helped you solve your problem, please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)